# Sharepoint list fields stored in content database?

Tags: database, sharepoint, list

I am trying to find out where data for Sharepoint List Fields are stored in the Content Database.

For example from the AllLists table filtering on the listid i am interested in I can derive the following Field from the tp_ContentTypes column:

```
<Field Type="CascadingDropDownListFieldWithFilter" DisplayName="Secondary Subject" Required="FALSE" ID="{b4143ff9-d5a4-468f-8793-7bb2f06b02a0}" SourceID="{6c1e9bbf-4f02-49fd-8e6c-87dd9f26158a}" StaticName="Secondary_x0020_Subject" Name="Secondary_x0020_Subject" ColName="nvarchar13" RowOrdinal="0" Version="1"><Customization><ArrayOfProperty><Property><Name>SiteUrl</Name><Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">http://extra.orange.net/knowhow</Value></Property><Property><Name>CddlName</Name><Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">SS</Value></Property><Property><Name>CddlParentName</Name><Value xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q3:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">PS</Value></Property><Property><Name>CddlChildName</Name><Value xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q4:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></Property><Property><Name>ListName</Name><Value xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q5:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Secondary</Value></Property><Property><Name>ListTextField</Name><Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Title</Value></Property><Property><Name>ListValueField</Name><Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Title</Value></Property><Property><Name>JoinField</Name><Value xmlns:q8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q8:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Primary</Value></Property><Property><Name>FilterField</Name><Value xmlns:q9="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q9:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Content Type ID</Value></Property><Property><Name>FilterOperator</Name><Value xmlns:q10="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q10:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Show All</Value></Property><Property><Name>FilterValue</Name><Value xmlns:q11="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q11:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></Property></ArrayOfProperty></Customization></Field>
```

Which table do I need to query to find the data held on this field?

Many Thanks
Nav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you already know that going to the SharePoint database is unsupported by Microsoft blah blah blah.

But theoretically speaking... I think what you're interested in is the `ColName="nvarchar13"` part of your XML. I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is stored in the `nvarchar13` column in the AllUserData table.

Comment: Thanks alot, how did you know this, were you referencing a database schema?

Comment: You can connect to the SharePoint database using Visual Studio's server connections. Unfortunately, I knew this because we corrupted our database after messing with Schema.xml files. :(